# How to hide the title of react navigation's TabNavigator I would like to show only Icon

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator

Inside screen i managed to hide title by setting it to empty like below

```
static navigationOptions = {
  title: "" 
};
```

but for every screen i have to set title as empty i  was wondering if there is any property to hide titles by default and only show icons ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referring to react-navigations [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab#tabBarOptions-for-TabBarTop-default-tab-bar-on-Android), you can use showLabel in tabBarOptions to hide the label. Default is set to true.

```
TabNavigator(
        {
          MyScreen: { screen: MyScreen }
        },
        {
          tabBarOptions: {
            showLabel: false,
            showIcon: true
          }
        }
      )
```

Comment: It works thanks i tries to find it in documentation before but the term title and label make confusion.